# Did Aeneas turn to the Lord with all the others in Lydda and Sharon?

Tags: acts, peter

In Acts 9:32-35

> 32 Now as Peter went here and there among them all, he came down also to the saints who lived at Lydda. 33 There he found a man named Aeneas, bedridden for eight years, who was paralyzed. 34 And Peter said to him, “Aeneas, Jesus Christ heals you; rise and make your bed.” And immediately he rose. 35 And **all** the residents of Lydda and Sharon saw him, and they turned to the Lord.

the text says all the residents of Lydda and Sharon saw Aeneas healed and turned to the Lord. Does this **all** include Aeneas, and how do we determine that?

Comment: Is there are reason to doubt the simple reading of this text?

Comment: By simple reading do you mean that he did? Jesus healed people that we know did not follow him.

Comment: That is not what the text says - The text says that they all tuned to the Lord.

Comment: All that saw him

Comment: Correct - all that saw the healed man turned to the Lord

Comment: Then what's the objection to asking whether Aeneas followed suit?

Comment: I assume that he did despite the text being silent on this matter.  However, the fact that when people saw the healed man (including the healed man who saw himself) turned to the Lord, then I guess he did.

Comment: This has now been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of Acts 9:32-35 makes the statement that "all who saw him [the man healed] turned to the Lord."  By any measure this is a successful evangelistic campaign.  The implication here is that this is a significant number.

Now, the "all" (v35, Greek: pantes) must have a defined set which, in this case, is explicitly defined - those that had seen the man healed.

It appears clear that those that had seen the man healed must include the man himself inasmuch as he experienced the healing and observed Peter act as the agent of divine healing power.  Therefore, since the healed man saw the healing, according to the text, he also tuned to the Lord.